# Add parents to nodes in tree?

Tags: java, tree

I have a tree structure and I want to be able to go through and add the parent node to a data parent variable that each child node has.

The structure of the tree is:

```
Class Tree {
     Node root;
}

Class Node {
     String data;
     Node parent;
     List<Node> children;
}
```

any suggestions?

EDIT to be more specific

```
 public void addParent() {
    for (Node child : curNode.children) {
        child.parent = curNode;
        curNode = child;
        findDFS(value);
    }
    return null;
}
```

with that code and the given tree:

```
     A
    /  \
   D    E
       / \
       B  S
```

E's parent is D when it should be A, why is that?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is very vague. Consider posting some examples of what you have tried and what problems you are facing.

Comment: I made it more specific

Comment: You mean E's parent is A? Also, can the parent only have 2 child or more than 2 child since you made a list for children?

Comment: By "specific", I think Daemon also meant more along the lines of: what is it that you're asking? Are you encountering an error? What is the expected behaviour, and what is the observed or actual behaviour?

Comment: I meant it E's parent is getting set to D when it should be A.

Comment: How are you building the tree?

Comment: Create a node n. Create node x,y,z. Create nodes a,b,c,d,e. Set x's children to a,b. Set y's children to c,d,e. Set n's children to x,y,z. Just an example.

Comment: What is the specific purpose of this tree? Usually tree nodes only contain children and to add a parent you create a new node and add the sub tree root to it as a child.

Comment: I need to be able to find the path to the list

Comment: From what? What are you pathing from? What do you have as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

> E's parent is D when it should be A, why is that?

In your loop you're doing:

```
for (Node child : curNode.children) {
    child.parent = curNode;
    curNode = child; // <-- problem is here!!!
    findDFS(value);
}
```

which means: in the first loop you're assigning the child to the current node and continue looping over the next child with the first child as a "parent" and then again...